# Name this insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This is the monsoon season and some black insects are flying in my house. They have a very bad smell. Does anyone know what is the name of that insect, including English and Hindi name?

[image: Image of the Black Insect]

Answer (score 2):

Your photo is not exactly the best one for species identification. However, since you said that it has a *"very bad smell"*, it seems to me that it is a bug (Hemiptera) from the Family [Pentatomidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomidae), which includes the *stink bugs*.

Quoting the Wikipedia page linked above:

> The stink bug derives its name from an unpleasant scent from a glandular substance released from pores in the thorax when disturbed. The chemicals involved include aldehydes, making the smell similar to that of coriander. In some species, the liquid contains cyanide compounds and a rancid almond scent, used to protect themselves and discourage predators.

I have never been to India, but in South America I've encountered some stink bugs which produced a very disgusting smell, some of them unbearable (for a couple of seconds only).

Here is a close view of a stink bug (this one is not from Asia and, therefore, probably not your species):

[image]

Finally, to narrow it down to the species, you have to check the Pentatomidae species in India.

Comment: I think it is the earth boring dung beetle from the family Geotrupidae.

Comment: The photo is not a stinkbug, and it doesn't look like any dung beetle I'm familiar with.  I agree with MB_7 that this is a member of the Cydnidae, which are noted for their foul smells.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit old but since I ended up here while searching for the same insect, here is what I believe is the insect in question (I also have an experience with it in our little garden).
Its name is: "burrowing bug" or sometime referred as "Cydnidae" (scientific name).

[image]

Also, check out this video (if it still remains) :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FABjzwRTeR4

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

[image: Earth boring dung beetle]

That's the earth boring dung beetle. It has a very bad smell and it belongs to the family Geotrupidae. You can learn more about it here https://www.britannica.com/animal/dung-beetle

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of them? As Their smell is very burst that if I flies on body and get rubbed. These insects are flying around my house as this is the rainy season.

Comment: @SagarGupta well you can check their source around your house and how they come into your house